# Indexer binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

This is probably a very stupid question, but I just cant figure it out.
Assuming that I have a data structure represented by these two classes:

```
class Accessor
{
}


class Row : INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public object this[Accessor index] {get;}
}
```

And if I also have a view-model like this:

```
class ViewModel
{
     public Row CurrentRow{get;}
     public Accessor CurrentAccessor {get;}
}
```

How can I define `CurrentRow[CurrentAccessor]` binding in XAML? I have tried using 
`{Binding Path=CurrentRow[{Binding Path=CurrentAccessor}]}`, but this doesn't seem to work.

**Update:** I should point out that Row class is a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, so using a simple property wrapper like this 
 `public object WrappedProperty { get{return CurrentRow[CurrentAccessor];}}` wouldn't work since then there will be no updates if the values stored in CurrentRow[CurrentAccessor] changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might change your Binding into a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) with an appropriate converter:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RowAccessorConverter}">
    <Binding Path="CurrentRow"/>
    <Binding Path="CurrentAccessor"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

The converter might look like this:

```
public class RowAccessorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var row = values[0] as Row;
        var accessor = values[1] as Accessor;
        return row[accessor];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but shouldn't it be `var accessor = values[1] as Accessor;` (Index 1 not index 0)

Comment: @Blachshma Exactly! Now you see that I didn't actually test that :-)

Answer (score 2):

In ViewModel you can create additional property.

```
class ViewModel
{
     public object Obj { get { return CurrentRow[CurrentAccessor]; } }
     public Row CurrentRow{ get; }
     public Accessor CurrentAccessor { get; }
}
```

And binding now is simple:

```
{Binding Obj}
```

Comment: That is a good answer :) and it was the first thing I have came up with, but it doesn't fit my case :\. I've updated my original question so that it matches my situation better. Plz check it out.